# Сортировка подсписка в списке

Tags: сортировка, list, prolog

Как сделать так, чтобы сортировался и подсписок.
Нужно:

```
?- elsort([d,s,a,[r,t,h]],X).
X = [a, d, s, [h, r, t]].
```

а получается:

```
?- elsort([d,s,a,[r,t,h]],X).
X = [a, d, s, [r, t, h]].
```

Вот сам код:

```
elsort([],[]).
    elsort([A|B],C):-
        elsort(B,D),
    elsortx(A,D,C).
    elsortx(A,[X|B],[X|C]):-
        order(X,A),
        !,
        elsortx(A,B,C).
    elsortx(A,B,[A|B]).
    order(A,A2):-
        A @< A2.
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```
% Сортировка списков, соджержащих подсписки
sort_nested( [], [] ).

sort_nested( [ H | T ], R ) :- 
    atomic( H ),
    sort_nested( T, W ),
    insert( H, W, R ).

sort_nested( [ X | T ], R ) :-
    \+ atomic( X ),
    sort_nested( X, Xs ),
    sort_nested( T, W ),
    insert( Xs, W, R ).

%
insert(X, [], [X]).
insert(X, [H|T], [X|L]):- X @< H, insert(H, T, L).
insert(X, [H|T], [H|L]):- X @>= H, insert(X, T, L).
```